# where to get precompiled binaries for Sox resampler library for android?

Tags: android, audio, ffmpeg, java-native-interface, sox

I have been using a sox precompiled binary from here https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java/tree/master/res/raw

but that binary only supports one cpu architecture. I am using a Galaxy s8 for testing so I need a binary that would support x86 and all other architecture including

I have tried building the [soxr](https://github.com/xxDroid/libsoxr-android) library by my self but I encountered too many errors. 
So I am looking for a link to download a precompiled binary for sox.